# Why so much room to the left of my labels in java?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel, preferredsize

Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {
    // Field members
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static Integer indexer = 1;
    static List<JLabel> listOfLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    static List<JTextField> listOfTextFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    static JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Construct frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(990, 990));
        frame.setTitle("My Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Frame constraints
        //GridBagConstraints frameConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Construct button
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        // Add button to frame
        //frameConstraints.gridx = 0;
        //frameConstraints.gridy = 0;
        //frame.add(addButton, frameConstraints);
        frame.add(addButton);

        // Construct panel
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder());

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel,   ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,  ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        // Add panel to frame
        //frameConstraints.gridx = 0;
        //frameConstraints.gridy = 1;
        //frameConstraints.weighty = 1;
        //frame.add(panel, frameConstraints);
        frame.add(scrollPane); 

        // Pack frame
        frame.pack();

        // Make frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Clear panel
            panel.removeAll();

            // Create label and text field
            //JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
            //jTextField.setSize(100, 200);
            //listOfTextFields.add(jTextField);
            listOfLabels.add(new JLabel("" + indexer));

            // Create constraints
            //GridBagConstraints textFieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

            // Add labels and text fields
            for (int i = 0; i < indexer; i++) {
                // Text field constraints
                //textFieldConstraints.gridx = 1;
                //textFieldConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                //textFieldConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
                //textFieldConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                //textFieldConstraints.gridy = i;

                // Label constraints
                labelConstraints.gridx = 0;
                labelConstraints.gridy = i;
                labelConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

                // Add them to panel
                panel.add(listOfLabels.get(i), labelConstraints);
                //panel.add(listOfTextFields.get(i), textFieldConstraints);
            }

            // Align components top-to-bottom
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = indexer;
            c.weighty = 1;
            c.ipady = 0;
            panel.add(new JLabel(), c);

            System.out.println("indexer is " + indexer);

            // Increment indexer
            indexer++;
            panel.updateUI();

            if(indexer ==2){

                listOfLabels.set(0, new JLabel("Test"));

            }

        }

        private int getWidth() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong? I want the labels to be justified all the way to the left. I don't have any padding set to the left so I am confused.

FYI, I found this code on stackoverflow and my goal is to have labels that I can dynamically add and update, hence I commented out the textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't call `setPreferredSize` on the scroll pane, this isn't what you should setting, use `GridBagConstraints` `weightx`/`y` and fill properties.
- Don't call `updateUI`, it doesn't do what you think it does, call `revalidate` instead, if you have to

The main reasons you're having problems is

1. You're call `setPreferredSize` on the panel. When adding components to a `GridBagLayout`, it will attempt to lay out components around the centre of the container
2. You've not specified a `weightx` or `anchor` property for the `GridBagConstraints` when adding the labels